# Dispose and create new DbContext

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-6, dbcontext

I'm working on a service, where every time it runs, it has to insert thousands of database records (it reads some documents, extracts parameters and then stores those parameters into the database). When it comes to only a few hundreds, there's no big problem, but as more records are being inserted, it gets slower. As far as I know, the main reason behind this is that my DbContext is keeping track of my objects to find any possible modification, and submit an update on a "SaveChanges()" call, and because of that, after a having a certain number of objects, it'll start to degrade its speed, because it'll need to keep track of more and more objects. 
I know that after certain point, I can get rid of my DbContext to start again from scratch, since I'll no longer need to keep track of those entities, so I tried something like this in my repository class (it'll only do it when it matches my criteria to dispose it):

```
_dbContext.Dispose();
_dbContext = new DbContext("connectionName");
```

But if I do it like that, the next time I try to access to the database, I get an exception, saying that my DbContext has been disposed.
I also tried just assigning a new instance of DbContext without disposing it first, like:

```
_dbContext = new DbContext("connectionName");
```

But by doing it like that, it still keeps all the objects in the _dbContext variable.
Since there are a lot of entities, I think that individually dettaching every object from the DbContext will be slower than just creating a new DbContext from scratch, but I don't get why it's not assigning the new DbContext instance (neither after disposing the previous one, nor when just assigning a new instance).

**Edit:** Just to give you a broader context of what I want to archieve.  I actually want the DbContext to keep track of my objects, but after a certain point, I'll not need to keep track of some objects anymore and I'll want it to keep track of a new bunch of objects. Like saying "forget everything you know, now you only care about the new objects that you'll receive". For example, let's say that I'm processing files for a customer, once I finish processing those files, the service will iterate over the next customer, but at this point, I don't really care about keeping track of the objects of the previous customer, and since we might be talking about a few hundreds or thousands of objects (multiple parameters and different entities being inserted into the database), I think that it might be better to just create a new DbContext from scratch, instead of iterating over all my objects to dettach them from my current the DbContext.

Comment: Why not [disable tracking on the objects](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg679352(v=vs.103).aspx) you retrieve but don't update?

Comment: Not sure this is the best approach.  Maybe post more detail about what you are trying to do.

Comment: @Scott and Paparazzi: Thank you for your answers! I updated the question with more details about what I want to archieve :)

Comment: Are you using single context for every customer? You should them change to one context for customer connection.

Comment: @Fals It's an instance per request, but since every service call can process information for multiple customers, then it'll use the same context for that processing. With customer, I'm not talking about a customer connecting and saying "hey, here, process all my data" and all the customers sharing that context with a singleton or something like that. It's a service that will run on a daily schedule, it'll crawl information from a folder and each bunch of files can be owned by a different customer, and when I finish processing a customer's data, is when I want to "re-create" my DbContext.

Comment: Have you considered using a micro OR/M like Dapper?

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer Actually our idea is to start the development using entity framework, and once everything is working correctly, start migrating it to PetaPoco (but Dapper also sounds like a good option). The main reason behind this is that the project is still in an early phase, and the client is still adding and modifying requirements, so EF makes it a lot easier to prepare fast demos and take decisions about what to add/modify. The only problem is when it get slower because it keeps track of objects that I don't want it to keep track anymore.